# NextJS URL rewrite creates duplicate pages?

Tags: next.js, url-rewriting

I just setup [URL rewrites in NextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) to translate my URLs for my multilingual website.

This is how my `next.config.js` file looks:

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ["da", "de"],
    defaultLocale: "da",
  },
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/de/ueber-uns",
        destination: "/de/om",
        locale: false,
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

So if you try to access *domain.com/de/ueber-uns* (which is a page that doesn't exist), the URL will show the content from the */de/om* page.

The problem is, that if you try to access */de/om*, that URL will not redirect to */de/ueber-uns*.

So I suspect that it will look like duplicate pages to Google/SEO and cause problems.

How can I avoid that (if possible)? Setting a redirect in `next.config.js` doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, and it seems like this is default behaviour since pages in `/pages/some/path` always produce valid routes. What I did was to also add redirects that go in the opposite direction, so in your case:

```
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/de/om",
        destination: "/de/ueber-uns",
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  }
```

This way the new URL still works, but the old one redirects to the new one. And by using the `permanent: true` it is my understanding that it won't impact SEO, since the NextJS documentation states:

> `permanent: true` will use the 308 status code which instructs
> clients/search engines to cache the redirect forever

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects

This worked for me, so if you are having issues maybe double check your config.